# Examples of file upload for Python Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob, google-app-engine-python

I tried Google's Python blobstore example [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-blobstore-python/blob/master/main.py), but it just redirects to a blank page at /_ah/upload/ which doesn't show the uploaded file. Is there something else that needs to run with this code, or does someone have a working example? I tried both the development server and full deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and the [example works](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-blobstore-python). You either dd not copy all the code or your app.yaml is not setup correctly. I would recommend downloading the whole project and alter it to do what you need until you understand how it works.